# How can I fill the circular sector of an elliptic shape with a color gradient?

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

What I want to do is to create this rotating cone visual effect.
I had previously used DirectX for that.

[image: cone]

What i have tried so far:

Even if I'm changing the thickness to `50` or more, the Arc is still not filled.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        var center = new Point(pictureBox1.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Height / 2);
        var innerR = 30;
        var thickness = 20;
        var startAngle = 0;
        var arcLength = 360;
        var outerR = innerR + thickness;
        var outerRect = new Rectangle
                        (center.X - outerR, center.Y - outerR, 2 * outerR, 2 * outerR);
        var innerRect = new Rectangle
                        (center.X - innerR, center.Y - innerR, 2 * innerR, 2 * innerR);

        using (var p = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            p.AddArc(outerRect, startAngle, arcLength);
            p.AddArc(innerRect, startAngle + arcLength, -arcLength);
            p.CloseFigure();
            e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Green, p);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Green, p);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to fill the arc even when the thickness is 20 or less.
Or when the value of the `innerR` radius changes.

The goal is to be able to fill the arc in any case.

[image: arc]

Comment: Not clear what closed Arc shape you want to fill that is not already filled. Can you post an image of the desired result?

Comment: @Jimi added desired result image.

Comment: So, you probably want to add the inner Arc first and Draw / Fill, then add the outer Arc and Draw / Fill the path (`Draw()` if you also want to draw the outer outline, not just the inner)

Comment: But it's not clear why you're using Arcs here instead of intersecting ellipses. In other words, there's the *suspect* that you're trying to generate some form of *dynamic shape*, but you didn't actually describe what that is. If you really want to draw *circles*, then do as previously described

Comment: If the sweep angle is 360, then draw/fill ellipses instead.

Comment: @Jimi my main goal was to draw a cone and that i will be able to rotate the cone inside the pictureBox 360 degress and to control the rotation speed to control the cone drawn angle if it will be like a circle or just partial circle(cone) and to control if it will be filled or not.  but the main goal is to draw a cone and to make it rotating inside the pictureBox. i thought to use arc for that.  i couldn't make it with drawpie.

Comment: @Jimi right , so i edited and explained what is my goal and what kind of cone i want to create.

Comment: If you mean that semi-transparent green shape or radar, it's a _Pie_. Use the `FillPie` method to draw it. To rotate (scanning effect), use a `Timer` to increase the `startAngle` till 360 then reset it. The `sweepAngle` is the size of that pie. Perhaps 360 / 8.

Comment: @dr.null i did it and it's working. but how do i get this color like in the image ? i can make the color transparent but then it wil not show anything.  how can i get that color i mean what is this color and how to make it in the code ? this my code : https://pastebin.com/jxK849aC

Comment: @dr.null found how to do it. not yet the color in the image maybe but the idea is: Color myPieColors = Color.FromArgb(150, Color.LightGreen);

Comment: Use `LinearGradientBrush`. Play with the two colors alpha channels. Like `color1 = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Green)` and `color2 = Color.FromArgb(20, Color.Green)` or so.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one method of drawing that cone.
It looks like a Radar sweep, so you may want to define the sweep angle and the rotation speed (how much the current rotation angle is increased based on the Timer's interval).
Using a standard System.Windows.Forms.Timer to invalidate the Canvas that contains the Image you're showing here.

The *Radar* contour (the external perimeter) is centered on the canvas and drawn in relation to the thickness specified (so it's always sized as the canvas bounds). It doesn't necessarily be a perfect circle, it can be elliptical (as in the image here)

The *Cone* section is drawn adding an Arc to a GraphicsPath and is closed drawing two lines, from the center point of the outer GraphicsPath to the starting and ending points of the Arc (I think this is a simple method to generate a curved conic figure, it can be used in different situations and lets you generate different shapes almost without calculations, see the code about this)

It's filled with a `LinearGradientBrush`, the section near the center has less transparency than the section near the border; adjust as required

Each time the rotation angle reaches `360°`, it's reset to `0`.
This is delegated to the Timer's `Tick` event handler

=> Built with .Net 7, but if you need to adapt it to .Net Framework, the only things to change are the syntax of the `using` blocks, remove the null-forgiving operator from here: `canvas!.ClientRectangle` and nullable reference types (e.g., change `object?` to just `object`)

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form {
    public SomeForm() {
        InitializeComponent();
        radarTimer.Interval = 100;
        radarTimer.Tick += RadarTimer_Tick;
    }

    float coneSweepAngle = 36.0f;
    float coneRotationAngle = .0f;
    float radarSpeed = 1.8f;
    float radarThickness = 5.0f;
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer radarTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    private void RadarTimer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e) {
        coneRotationAngle += radarSpeed;
        coneRotationAngle %= 360.0f;
        canvas.Invalidate();
    }

    private void canvas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
        var center = new PointF(canvas.Width / 2.0f, canvas.Height / 2.0f);
        RectangleF outerRect = canvas!.ClientRectangle;
        outerRect.Inflate(-(radarThickness / 2.0f), -(radarThickness / 2.0f));

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        using var pathOuter = new GraphicsPath();
        using var pathInner = new GraphicsPath();
        pathOuter.AddEllipse(outerRect);

        pathInner.StartFigure();
        pathInner.AddArc(outerRect, coneRotationAngle, coneSweepAngle);
        var arcPoints = pathInner.PathPoints;
        PointF first = arcPoints[0];
        PointF last = arcPoints[arcPoints.Length - 1];
        pathInner.AddLines(new[] { center, last, center, first });
        pathInner.CloseFigure();

        using var outerPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red), radarThickness);
        using var innerBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(
            center, first, Color.FromArgb(200, Color.Orange), Color.FromArgb(20, Color.Orange));

        e.Graphics.FillPath(innerBrush, pathInner);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(outerPen, pathOuter);
    }
}
```

This is how it works:

[image]