# How to draw a circle around the other distance in the image ? or any distance?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public void DrawLine(PictureBox pb, Graphics g)
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Red, 2f), 0, 0, pb.Size.Width, pb.Size.Height);
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            DrawLine(pictureBox1, e.Graphics);
        }
```

the result is the red circle at the range a bit before of the 300 kilometers.
but what if i want to make the circle to be drawn on the circle of the 200 kilometers or even the inner circle the smaller one(100 kilometers) ?

how to calculate where to draw the circle and what size ?

the image size is 512x512

[image: circle in red]

I added another cone called it innerOuterRect but how do i make it shorter or longer depending on kilometers distance from the center ?

later i want to add a textBox and when i enter kilometers for example 100 it will move the cone size to 100 kilometers radius and if change it to 21.3 kilometers so the cone and so on.

so the first cone will stay the same and the second one to be changed in kilometers.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var center = new PointF(pictureBox1.Width / 2.0f, pictureBox1.Height / 2.0f);
            RectangleF outerRect = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle;
            RectangleF innerOuterRect = pictureBox1.ClientRectangle;
            outerRect.Inflate(-(radarThickness / 2.0f), -(radarThickness / 2.0f));
            innerOuterRect.Inflate(-(radarThickness / 2.0f), -(radarThickness / 2.0f));

            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            var pathOuter = new GraphicsPath();
            var pathInner = new GraphicsPath();
            pathOuter.AddEllipse(outerRect);
            pathOuter.AddEllipse(innerOuterRect);
            pathInner.StartFigure();
            pathInner.AddArc(outerRect, coneRotationAngle, coneSweepAngle);
            //pathInner.AddArc(innerOuterRect, coneRotationAngle, coneSweepAngle);
            var arcPoints = pathInner.PathPoints;
            PointF first = arcPoints[0];
            PointF last = arcPoints[arcPoints.Length - 1];
            pathInner.AddLines(new[] { center, last, center, first });
            pathInner.CloseFigure();

            var outerPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red), radarThickness);
            var innerBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(
                center, first, Color.FromArgb(200, Color.Orange), Color.FromArgb(20, Color.Orange));

            e.Graphics.FillPath(innerBrush, pathInner);
            e.Graphics.DrawPath(outerPen, pathOuter);
        }
```

Comment: You can probably take [the answer I've posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74622050/7444103) in a previous, very similar, question of yours. You can see the inner Path that defines the rotating cone: `pathInner.AddArc(outerRect, coneRotationAngle, coneSweepAngle);`. This equates the cone size to the outer circle. You can just define another, smaller, region that falls inside the outer circle, sized in relation to the dimensions of the outer region. I.e., if the current whole region represents 300km and the inner region is 100km, you size the inner region as a third of the outer

Comment: Replace `outerRect` with a rectangle where the dimensions are a third of the `outerRect` dimensions (it's a circular region, so not much of a calculation there) -- You could also add controls that define the different details; you can see the sweep angle and the rotation velocity in the sample animation. Adding the length of the cone is very simple

Comment: @Jimi i edited my question with what i tried. i added another cone but how do i change it's length by kilometers from the center ? now it's the same size as the first cone.

Answer (score 1):

To determine the scale between the outer region and the region that defines the cone of the Radar, you can take the maximum size of the outer region. For example:

The outer region's maximum size is 300km:

```
float radarSizeMeters = 300.0f * 1000f;
```

The cone's region is a third of the outer region or a specific size:

```
float radarConeSizeMeters = radarSizeMeters / 3.0f;
// Or use a fixed size, depending on the use case
float radarConeSizeMeters = 10.873f * 1000;
```

Then the scale is a value between `.0f` and `1.0f`:

```
 float radarConeScale = radarConeSizeMeters / radarSizeMeters;
```

Having determined the relation between the outer and inner regions, you then use this scale factor to scale the graphic elements that define the two regions:

```
var outerRegion = [Canvas].ClientRectangle;
var innerRegion = new RectangleF(0, 0, 
    outerRegion.Width * radarConeScale, outerRegion.Height * radarConeScale
);
```

Then set the new location, based on the calculated size.
The center point is known in advance and doesn't change:

```
var center = new PointF(canvas.Width / 2.0f, canvas.Height / 2.0f);
// [...]
innerRegion.Location = new PointF(
    center.X - innerRegion.Width / 2.0f, 
    center.Y - innerRegion.Height / 2.0f
);
```

In the sample code I'm doing the same thing, but using `RectangleF.Inflate()`, to deflate the inner region by half of the calculated measure.
`RectangleF.Inflate()` resizes the rectangle proportionally and also moves the Location

You can specify:

- `radarSizeMeters`, which represents the size in meters of the whole region
- `radarConeSizeMeters`, represents the size in meters of the cone's region
- `coneSweepAngle`, which defines the amplitude of the visible cone
- `radarSpeed` is the speed of the rotation. To set the rounds per minute (RPM):

  ```
  radarSpeed = (360.0f * [Rounds per minute]) / 60 / (1000 / [Timer Interval]);
  ```

with `[Timer Interval] = 100` (approximated)

Note that I'm targeting .NET 7 and the language version is C# 11, `nullable` enabled. For example, this:
`PointF last = arcPoints[^1];` is the same as `PointF last = arcPoints[arcPoints.Length - 1];`

=> You **must** declare the GraphicsPaths, Pens and Brushes with `using` statements.
***Must***, not *should*

```
public partial class frmRadar : Form {
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer radarTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

    float coneSweepAngle = 36.0f;
    float coneRotationAngle = .0f;
    float radarSpeed = 1.98f;  // ~3 RPM, based on Timer.Interval
    float radarThickness = 5.0f;
    float radarSizeMeters = 32.620f * 1000;
    float radarConeSizeMeters = 10.873f * 1000;
    Color radarConeColor = Color.Orange;

    public frmRadar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        radarTimer.Interval = 100;
        radarTimer.Tick += RadarTimer_Tick;
    }

    private void RadarTimer_Tick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        coneRotationAngle += radarSpeed;
        coneRotationAngle %= 360.0f;
        canvas.Invalidate();
    }

    private void canvas_Paint(object? sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var center = new PointF(canvas.Width / 2.0f, canvas.Height / 2.0f);
        RectangleF outerRect = canvas!.ClientRectangle;
        outerRect.Inflate(-(radarThickness / 2.0f), -(radarThickness / 2.0f));

        using var pathRadarOuterRegion = new GraphicsPath();
        using var pathConeRegion = new GraphicsPath();
        pathRadarOuterRegion.AddEllipse(outerRect);

        float radarConeScale = radarConeSizeMeters / radarSizeMeters;
        SizeF radarConeScaleSize = new(
            (outerRect.Width - (outerRect.Width * radarConeScale)) / -2.0f,
            (outerRect.Height - (outerRect.Height * radarConeScale)) / -2.0f);
        var coneRect = outerRect;
        coneRect.Inflate(radarConeScaleSize);

        pathConeRegion.AddArc(coneRect, coneRotationAngle, coneSweepAngle);
        var arcPoints = pathConeRegion.PathPoints;
        PointF first = arcPoints[0];
        PointF last = arcPoints[^1];
        pathConeRegion.AddLines(new[] { last, center, first, center });
        pathConeRegion.CloseFigure();

        using var outerPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red), radarThickness);
        using var innerBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(
            center, first, Color.FromArgb(200, radarConeColor), Color.FromArgb(20, radarConeColor));

        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.FillPath(innerBrush, pathConeRegion);
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(outerPen, pathRadarOuterRegion);
    }
}
```